# Updating a Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have an 8.1 app in the Windows Store and it is currently being bought and used by customers.  I have made some changes to the app that I want to deploy out to my testers.  From what I've read, I should update the app and set it's distribute and visibility to Hide and Prevent Acquisition so that only my testers can download it.

If I change the visibility in the update, does that mean that no one can download the previously deployed version anymore?  The goal here is to involve testers in an automated fashion via the store without affecting the app in production until it's been tested and approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, **you can't do that**.. if you, this will effect the whole submission (even the public)..

What I suggest to do (and all the beta apps providers are doing including me) is to create another app -submission- marked as ***preview*** and thought this you can submit any beta versions, and when a release is ready.. you can push the last beta to the ***public*** app :) .